# access class property in workflow foundation

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

so i am already invoking a workflow activity, with the "dataSet" containing an instance of my class Employee...

```
WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(wfManager.Activity, dataSet);
```

My Employee has a property called Department.
What i want is to edit a condition in my workflow xaml, but i am going to make it like this:

```
Employee.Department == "RND"
```

i am doing this in VS2012, and when i type Employee in the condition editor, i cannot access its properties. I just put my activity xaml file in the same project with my Employee class. What should i do more to access my class properties inside the activity xaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to define an InArgument and map the external data to the arguments using a Dictionary. With that in place the object is available through the argument name.

See [this blog post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2009/10/23/workflow-parameters-in-window-workflow-foundation-4.aspx) on how to pass data to an workflow.